# Deploy a general tree model in flask

Tags: python, flask, serialization, deployment

### Background

I have a class that holds a general tree data structure (called **Factory** class). This general tree is composed of nodes (called **Item** class) that can have multiple parents nodes and multiple child nodes. Also, parents and children can be shared.
For those familiar with manufacturing and supply chain terms, these classes model a "bill of materials".

This class is instantiated by reading +50Mio. records from a database, thus it takes some minutes to instantiate the object.

Given that, my question is: how can I deploy this model using flask?

#### Try 1

Everytime an user sends a request, the model reads the entire database, instantiates the model, calls a given method in this object and returns the output to the user. This takes way too long, every requests would take several minutes to be completed.

#### Try 2

Serialise the model using `pickle` or `dill`, so everytime the user sends and request, the modle is de-serialised, a given method is invoked and the output returned to the user. The problem here is that the model is highly recursive and `pickle` or `dill` are not able to serialise it without hitting the maximum recursion limit.

I tried to increase the maximum recursion limit with `sys.setrecursionlimit()`, but python crashes before the serialisation is complete.

Comment: Is it possible to load the data once before processing any requests, say at application start?

Comment: It's possible, but loading the data is taking several minutes. So when the user first access the URL, it takes several minutes for the page to load. I tried it with the decorator `@app.before_first_request`